# PlatformException Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-notification

What is this error?
I was building a demo app to for Android and IOS notifications then this error appeared when I ran the project:

> PlatformException (PlatformException(error, null, null,
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
> android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2429)     at
> android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2409)   at
> android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2392)     at
> android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2334)     at
> android.app.INotificationManager$Stub$Proxy.createNotificationChannels(INotificationManager.java:3933)
> at
> android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannels(NotificationManager.java:928)
> at
> android.app.NotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(NotificationManager.java:916)
> at
> com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.setupNotificationChannel(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:999)
> at
> com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.createNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:203)
> at
> com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.showNotification(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1035)
> at
> com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1376)
> at
> com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.onMethodCall(FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.java:1245)
> at
> io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel$IncomingMethodCallHandler.onMessage(MethodChannel.java:262)
> at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.invokeHandler(DartMessenger.java:295)
> at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger.lambda$dispatchMessageToQueue$0$io-flutter-embedding-engine-dart-DartMessenger(DartMessenger.java:319)
> at
> io.flutter.embedding.engine.dart.DartMessenger$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0.run(Unknown
> Source:12)    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)  at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)   at
> android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7842)     at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)    at
> com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548)
> at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1003)
> Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:    at com.android.internal.util.Preconditions.checkArgument(Preconditions.java:44)
> at
> com.android.server.notification.PreferencesHelper.createNotificationChannel(PreferencesHelper.java:833)
> at
> com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$11.createNotificationChannelsImpl(NotificationManagerService.java:3714)    at
> com.android.server.notification.NotificationManagerService$11.createNotificationChannels(NotificationManagerService.java:3735)
> at
> android.app.INotificationManager$Stub.onTransact(INotificationManager.java:1548)
> ))

And this code where the error is located:

> import
> 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
> import 'package:rxdart/subjects.dart'; import
> 'package:timezone/timezone.dart' as tz; import
> 'package:timezone/data/latest.dart' as tz;
>
> class LocalNotificationService {   LocalNotificationService();
>
> final _localNotificationService = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();
>
> Future intialize() async {
> tz.initializeTimeZones();
> const AndroidInitializationSettings androidInitializationSettings =
> AndroidInitializationSettings('@drawable/ic_stat_circle_notifications');
>
> ```
> IOSInitializationSettings iosInitializationSettings =
>     IOSInitializationSettings(
>   requestAlertPermission: true,
>   requestBadgePermission: true,
>   requestSoundPermission: true,
>   onDidReceiveLocalNotification: onDidReceivLocalNotification,
> );
> final InitializationSettings settings = InitializationSettings(
>   android: androidInitializationSettings,
>   iOS: iosInitializationSettings,
> );
> await _localNotificationService.initialize(
>   settings,
>   onSelectNotification: onSelectNotification,
> );   }
> ```
>
> Future _NotificationDetails() async {
> const AndroidNotificationDetails androidNotificationDetails =
> AndroidNotificationDetails(
> '',
> '',
> importance: Importance.max,
> priority: Priority.max,
> playSound: true,
> );
> const IOSNotificationDetails iosNotificationDetails =
> IOSNotificationDetails();
> return const NotificationDetails(
> android: androidNotificationDetails,
> );   }
>
> Future showNotification({
> required int id,
> required String title,
> required String body,   }) async {
> final details = await _NotificationDetails();
> await _localNotificationService.show(
> id,
> title,
> body,
> details,
> );   }
>
> Future showSchedualedNotification({
> required int id,
> required String title,
> required String body,
> required int seconds,   }) async {
> final details = await _NotificationDetails();
> await _localNotificationService.zonedSchedule(
> id,
> title,
> body,
> tz.TZDateTime.from(
> DateTime.now().add(Duration(seconds: seconds)),
> tz.local,
> ),
> details,
> androidAllowWhileIdle: true,
> uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
> UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
> );   }
>
> void onDidReceivLocalNotification(
> int id, String? title, String? body, String? payload) {
> print('id $id');   }
>
> void onSelectNotification(String? payload) {
> print('paylod $payload');   } }

Comment: Please provide some more detail

Comment: What does your code look like?

Comment: I just added the code, will you please take a look?